# Installing gtk2.0 on raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am quite new or Rasperry Pi and am working on an object detection project that I found online. I am having an issue when trying to install gtk2.0 on the PI. Its like the repo simply wont download for me.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

When trying to install the package it is able to retrieve the information about the package but not able to install it as seen in the screenshots below.
[image: Retrieving the package]

[image: Installing the package]

I have tried both Bullseye and Buster os for the PI and still the same issue.
I have installed gtk3.0 but still faces with the same issue if I try and run the final code.

- also have tried downloading the package on multiple different networks and its still the same

[image: Running script]

Any help would you be greatly appreciated as I really am losing hope for this project

The project guide I am following ishttps://core-electronics.com.au/guides/object-identify-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Seems like some packages failed with a 503 when downloading. This _may_ be transient - if you try the install again, does it still fail? Have you also run `apt-get update` recently to make sure all your metadata is up to date?

Comment: Yes I have tried the install again and still no joy. Also updated everything is I really don't know 

Comment: Does this help. sudo apt-get install libgtk-4-dev It worked for me.

Comment: @toyotaSupra that just says package does not exist?

Comment: Did u apt- update and apt-upgrade?